# select inner-level index data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
np.random.seed(0)
data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(18).reshape(9,2),
                 index=[['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'],
                        [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3]], columns = [1,2])
data1
Out[1]: 
            1         2
a 1  1.764052  0.400157
  2  0.978738  2.240893
  3  1.867558 -0.977278
b 1  0.950088 -0.151357
  3 -0.103219  0.410599
c 1  0.144044  1.454274
  2  0.761038  0.121675
d 2  0.443863  0.333674
  3  1.494079 -0.205158
```

I wanna select rows based on inner level index =2.
It seems data1.xs(2,level=1) will achieve this.

```
data1.xs(2,level=1)

    Out[2]: 
          1         2
a  0.978738  2.240893
c  0.761038  0.121675
d  0.443863  0.333674
```

Is this the best way to do this by using xs? can i use something like loc.
I know if there is a pandas series, i can use mySeries.loc[:,2] to achieve this. Can we do a similar thing to DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve your DataFrame index levels, use `loc(axis=0)`:

```
data1.loc(axis=0)[:, 2]

            1         2
a 2  0.978738  2.240893
c 2  0.761038  0.121675
d 2  0.443863  0.333674
```

`xs` will select and index on the level, and you lose that level in the result.
Alternatively, specify `drop_level=False` with `xs` so that does not happen:

```
data1.xs(2, level=1, drop_level=False)

            1         2
a 2  0.978738  2.240893
c 2  0.761038  0.121675
d 2  0.443863  0.333674
```

Thing with pandas is that there's often no single/best way to do something. Do whatever feels best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` indexing with a tuple:

```
data1.loc[(slice(None),2),:]

           1        2
a 2 0.978738  2.24089
c 2 0.761038 0.121675
d 2 0.443863 0.333674
```